# When running "ng lint" in a clean Angular project eslint gives errors for a completely different project in another folder

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, eslintrc

I have a very strange issue with Eslint and Angular. Every time I run ***ng lint*** I get errors such as:

> An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot read config file: [COMPLETELY_DIFFERENT_PROJECT_PATH]\node_modules\eslint-config-prettier@typescript-eslint.js
> Error: "prettier/@typescript-eslint" has been merged into "prettier" in eslint-config-prettier 8.0.0. See: https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#version-800-2021-02-21
> Referenced from: [COMPLETELY_DIFFERENT_PROJECT_PATH]\node_modules@nestjs\axios.eslintrc.js
> See "[USER]\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-H0X9RR\angular-errors.log" for further details.

Note that these errors occur in a completely different project and a completely different folder than the project I'm running the ***ng lint*** command from.

To verify this issue I created a completely new and fresh Angular project using

> ng new

And then add eslint schematics using

> ng add @angular-eslint/schematics

This generates the following project files:

**.eslintrc.json**

```
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "projects/**/*"
  ],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.ts"
      ],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": [
          "tsconfig.json"
        ],
        "createDefaultProgram": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "attribute",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "camelCase"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "element",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "kebab-case"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "files": [
        "*.html"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "new-angular-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.3.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.3.5",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "13.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "13.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "13.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "13.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "13.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.3.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.17.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.17.0",
    "eslint": "^8.12.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.2"
  }
}
```

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "newAngularProject": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/new-angular-project",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "newAngularProject:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "newAngularProject:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "newAngularProject:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "src/**/*.ts",
              "src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "newAngularProject",
  "cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@angular-eslint/schematics"
  }
}
```

But even for a completely clean project running ***ng lint*** still gives me errors about files that are in a completely different folder than the project I'm running it from. I already searched high and low for a solution but I can't seem to find any solution to this.

What I also find strange is that the eslint extension in VSCode for detecting linting issues while you're programming **does** work: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint

I'm completely stumped by this. Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: could you please check wether "npm run lint" is working fine?

Comment: Remove node_modules folder and type npm i, it solves most of the problems.

Comment: "npm run lint" has the same result

Comment: This was tried on a completely freshly installed project. Removing node_modules folder and re-running npm i didn't solve the issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the complete solution based on Idan Rokach's answer. I ended up adding `"lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts src"` to `package.json` to only perform linting on the `src` folder. Still not sure what the underlying root cause was, but at least this works.

Answer (score 2):

Try to specify the working directory `eslint --ext .js,.ts .` the `.` or, `ng lint --files=src/**/*.ts`.
You can add this to `package.json` as: `lint:eslint --ext .js,.ts .` and run `npm run lint`

Comment: That does work somewhat! Is there also a way to specify eslint to only check in src? Because the ng lint --files=src/**/*.ts command you suggested is not supported